# Is the daily quota limit in Firebase applied per user or for all users?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm confused with Firebase's quota limit. Is the 20k writes per day consumable per user or for all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's *per project* irrespective of how many users you have.

Comment: Does the 20k writes mean 20k documents you can write per day or 20k times (or the number) of write operations per day?

Comment: @VinceMelmarYbañez 20K write operations, it could be 1 document being created and updated 20K times or 20K documents being created once.

Comment: After you have consumed your 20k writes per day, you can no longer write to Firebase?

Comment: @VinceMelmarYbañez if you are on Spark plan then no, the API will throw "resource-exhausted" error and you'll have to wait for daily reset. If you are on the Blaze (pay as you go) plan then no, you will be charged after the daily free quota has been exhausted.

Comment: Oh thanks! But for now I have to stay in Spark Plan